# How to auto start apache tomcat server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I can view the webpage after deploying the war file.when i open the page for next day i cannot view the page again after restarting the apache tomcat server the page opens.

Comment: In which OS are you deploying your app?

Comment: For Linux you can refer : http://wiki.brekeke.com/wiki/Auto-Start-Tomcat-when-reboot-Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have shut down the machine. When you come on next day and access the same URL then you won't be able to see that page. You will have to restart the tomcat server again to see that page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use `Linux` and encountered the same issue when security patches/ OS hardening is performed on the server where apache tomcat runs. Below is the way I tackled the problem starting tomcat right after server reboots.

You will need to use `CronScheduler` and is pretty easy. The Cron daemon is a built-in Linux utility that runs processes on your system at a scheduled time.

```
Open a Terminal
Type --> crontab –e
Add following Line into Crontab --> @reboot [path to tomcat`s startup.sh shell script in tomcat`s bin directory]
Press ESC key and Press ':' and Type "wq" (Save the changes into Cron via VIM/ VI)
Type crontab -l (This will show you the reboot statement added means all OK)
```

The job defined by this string runs at startup, immediately after Linux reboots.